# Ignore tap until page fully loaded

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

I have page1 with a button that opens page2. Page2 takes approx 1 second to open and contains a list of options (user controls) that when tapped, saves the selection and returns the user to page1.

When the user taps the button on page1, if they become impatient, they will tap it again before page2 has loaded/displayed. the problem is, that the tap is recognised and the first option on page2 is tapped, even though it's not yet visible. This then saves the selection and returns the user to page1.

Is there anyway I can stop the tap/click event being recognised until the page2 has fully loaded?

Answer (score 0):

One idea may be to subscribe to the *Tap/Click* event in *OnNaviagatedTo* on first page, then inside *Tap/Click* event unsubscribe it, so that user won't be able to click it again. Then when he navigates back, *OnNavigatedTo* subscribes again. You may also think about flag that will be set up upon *Tap/Click* and dismissed in *Loaded* event of second page. Sample:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnNavigatedTo");
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        this.button.Click += Button_Click;
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Button).Click -= Button_Click;
        await Task.Delay(1000); // simulate heavy load of second page
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually - I don't think this will work as it's not the second tap of the button on page1 causing the issue - it's the second tap of what the user thinks is the button on page1 but is actually a tap of the controls on page2 - but your idea of the flags on page2 should do it.

Comment: @Rick What takes so long for the page to load? Maybe you can subscribe to the event in second page after the heavy job or in *Loaded* event?

Comment: I *think* it's the fact i'm using UserControls - I started off with them on an emulator and no issues, but now we're on the device it seems to be really slow. Google suggested UserControls are NOT what I should be using. It's a bit late in the day to change it but what do you think? I might be forced to change.

Comment: Have you tried with *Loaded* events? Can you share a sample with the problem?

Comment: In the Loaded event of page two, I just tried looping through all the UserControls "activating" the click events (by setting a flag to true and checking this in the user control click event) but it doesn't seem to have any effect. It's difficult to share tbh.

Comment: What do you think about the UserControl - I'm loading 200+ to the page (a list of countries). Google suggests I should be using MVVM - what do you think?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the sample. Are you using any list or something? Any asynchronous data loading?